# Parcing preceeding comments in YAML with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

### My problem

I have a yaml with comments like this

```yaml
# comment A
a: 1  # also comment a
# comment B
b:  # comment B
  # comment B1
  b1: 1 # comment b1 
  b2: 2 # comment b2
# comment C
c: 3
```

When i'm trying to parse this with ruamel.yaml (to sort it against another yaml, keeping comments attached to right keys), i'm getting comments associated with wrong keys:

```py
root [None, [CommentToken('# comment A\n', line: 1, col: 0)]]
a [None, None, CommentToken('# also comment a\n# comment B\n', line: 2, col: 6), None]
b [None, None, CommentToken('# comment B\n  # comment B1\n', line: 4, col: 4), None]
b1 [None, None, CommentToken('# comment b1 \n', line: 6, col: 8), None]
b2 [None, None, CommentToken('# comment b2\n# comment C\n', line: 7, col: 8), None]
```

Is there a way to make ruamel.yaml attach comments to corresponding keys properly?

Examples how i want them to be:

```py
b1 [None, CommentToken('# comment B\n', line: x, col: x), CommentToken('# comment b1 \n', line: x, col: x), None]
b2 [None, None, CommentToken('# comment b2\n', line: x, col: x), None]
c [None, None, CommentToken('# comment C\n', line: x, col: x), None]
```

versions:

```
python=3.9.5
ruamel.yaml=0.17.16
```

### What I tried

```py
y = YAML(typ='rt', pure=True)
y.comment_handling = C_PRE
```

But looks like it isn't supposed to work this way:

```
  File "...\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 1531, in construct_mapping
    if value_node.comment[2]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

`typ="rtsc"`, but it doesn't work for my case (can post full stacktrace if needed):

```
  File "...\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\emitter.py", line 683, in expect_block_mapping_key
    if self.event.comment and self.event.comment[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: This looks all good to me, and behaviour is as documented. `ruamel.yaml` combines end of line comments (even empty ones) with following empty lines and full-comment-lines into one single multi-lne comment that attaches to the last node parsed. I have started looking into that not doing things that way (with different scheme for splitting the mult-line comment and attaching some to the next-node), but I currently have some trouble financing that work.

Comment: @Anthon so, there is no way to change the way how library attaches comments to keys in current implementation? Oh well, thanks for answer anyway! Hope you'll be able to make different implementation eventually.

Oh, and speaking of documenting: a little more comments in the code would be handy too, it wasn't easy to figure out how Comment objects are stored in ca.items dictionary =)

Comment: The comments are there on the data, otherwise it could not be preserved. But with the current way of attaching, it is non-trivial to walk over the data-structure and re-assign these.